# Is it possible to Cascade.All() EXCEPT Delete?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am getting a list of objects separately (and not from NHibernate) and setting the parent objects IEnumerable equal to this returned object. Originally, we only needed to read the objects.  Then we had the need to update only specific fields on the parent.  Recently, we needed to update fields on the child.  So far, all was well with SaveOrUpdate().  Now, I need to update the children even if the collection of children was attached to a detached parent object (not using NHibernate).  The following code results in the parent being updated, but not the children.  If I do all, then the children would be deleted if the parent does not have a collection.  I do not want to do this because I am worried about legacy uses of this that does not account for this behavior.

DESIRED BEHAVIOR:
 1. Cascade any changes to the collection (whether in the parent was retrieved by NHibernate or not).
 2. Do not delete objects even if the parent does not have a collection of children.

Is this possible?

This is our NHibernate save method:

```
[Transaction]
public int? Save(DocumentFieldDTO entity, bool autoFlush)
{
    var persisted = CurrentSession.Merge(entity);

    entity.DocumentFieldID = persisted.DocumentFieldID;
    if (autoFlush) { CurrentSession.Flush(); }
    return entity.DocumentFieldID;
}
```

The DocumentFieldDTOMap looked like this:

```
public class DocumentFieldDTOMap : EntityMapBase
{

    public DocumentFieldDTOMap()
    {    
        Table("DocumentField");

        Id(m =&gt; m.DocumentFieldID).GeneratedBy.Increment().UnsavedValue(null);

        Map(x =&gt; x.Name);

        Map(x =&gt; x.DocumentSectionID).Not.Update();
        // .... Lots of other fields ....//

        HasMany(x =&gt; x.DocumentFieldOrgs)
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
        .LazyLoad()
        .KeyColumn("DocumentFieldID");
        }
    }
```

}

If I change `Cascade.SaveUpdate()` to `Cascade.All()` the updates work, but will also delete.  I want to eliminate the delete capability.

UPDATE (1/27/2014):

I just verified that the deletes were cascading when the mapping was `SaveUpdate()`, so this isn't as big an issue since I am not changing the existing functionality.  I would still like to be able to update all cascading EXCEPT delete.  An solution, if possible, would be great for future reference.

UPDATE (2/10/2014)

The following is the tests that verify that the children are deleted when cascade is "SaveUpdate()".  The `GetDocumentFieldDTOWithADO(DocumentFieldID)` uses the same transaction as NHibernate and has 318 DocumentFieldOrgs on the first call (before the save) and 0 when called after the save.  Maybe there is an issue with the test?  Does it delete the children because I call Merge?

```
    [Test]
    public void Save_ShouldDeleteDocumentFieldOrgs_WhenSavingDocumentFieldWithoutDocFieldOrgsList()
    {
        //arrange
        var expectedDocField = GetDocumentFieldDTOWithADO(DocumentFieldID);
        expectedDocField.DocumentFieldOrgs = null;

        //act
        Repository.Save(expectedDocField, false);
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().FlushAndEvict(expectedDocField);

        //assert
        var actualDocField = GetDocumentFieldDTOWithADO(DocumentFieldID);

        actualDocField.DocumentFieldOrgs.Should()
            .BeEmpty("DocumentFieldOrgs should be deleted if the parent does not have a child collection");        
    }
```

UPDATED (2/11/2014) - Radim was correct in his answer below.  NHibernate did not delete the children.  It disassociated them from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE, reflecting the query changes

The test you've showed in the query update, has proven:

> If the `parent.Children` is set to `null` and persited, it will have NO children - next time accessed.

Let me explain what happened, let me use some virtual language *(Attention I am using **`Parent`** and **`Children`** to make it simple)*

1) mapping of the parent child is `cascade="save-update"`
This is an information for NHibernate that during creation or amending, children collection should be passed the Save() or Update() calls

2) Let's load parent

```
var session = ... // get a ISession for our test
var parent = session.Get<Parent>(1); // e.g. DocumentFieldDTO 

// NOT Empty -- is true:  IsNotEmpty()
Assert.IsTrue(parent.Children.IsNotEmpty()); // e.g. DocumentFieldOrgs
```

3) Now, remove the reference and check what NHibernate will do:

```
parent.Children = null;

session.Flush();
session.Clear();
```

Here is the SQL statement executed:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [schema].[Child_Table] 
      SET ParentId = null WHERE ParentId = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

As we can see, because of the mapping `save-update`, NHibernate did handle this scenario, by removing the reference. In fact by UPDATing the child table

4) Load `Parent` again

```
parent = session.Get<Parent>(1);

// EMPTY -- is true: IsEmpty()
Assert.IsTrue(parent.Children.IsEmpty());
```

Summary: 
As we've seen above, NHibernate is doing what was mapped, and expected. No delete. Just an update, removing the reference

PREVIOUS part of this Answer

The answer is: change your `public int? Save(...)` implementation. NHibernate cascading is working as expected, please read more here [Ayende, NHibernate Cascades: the different between all, all-delete-orphans and save-update](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update)

First take a look at the statement above:

> DESIRED BEHAVIOR:
>   1) Cascade any changes to the collection (**whether in the parent was retrieved by NHibernate or not**).
>   2) Do not delete objects even if the **parent does not have a collection of children**.

The bold parts are the reason, why the `Cascade concept` is not working. Because:

> Cascade makes sense only if an operation on
>    the **existing** parent is cascaded / repeated / passed
>    the **existing/known** child(children)

NHiberante cascade implementation realy does work this way: [9.9. Lifecyles and object graphs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-graphs) *(an extract)*

> Mapping ... with `cascade="all"` marks the association as a parent/child style relationship where save/update/deletion of the parent results in save/update/deletion of the child(ren). ... **A child which becomes unreferenced by its parent is not automatically deleted**, except in the case of a `<one-to-many>` association mapped with cascade="all-delete-orphan"...

Not only it is not deleted. If it is not referenced, it does not recieve a trigger to any type of cascading operation.

Suggestion:

Adjust the `Save()` method, to do two operations:

1. Update the parent
2. Find the *"children"* or better - the somehow related items. Load them adjust them, and call `session.Flush()`. Any changes on objects referenced by *ISession* will be persisted.

Comment: I don't understand your response.  NHibernate will delete the child records from the database if the parent POCO object does not have any child POCO objects.  I could implement change management of the children in the save implementation, but I want NHibernate to deal with the object mapping and change management.  I guess I was hoping that there was some implementation of the mapping or SaveUpdate/Merge methods that could instruct NHibernate to update records, but never delete an object.  There is good control over what you can update, but not what gets deleted.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your question. Cascading is working this way: 1) There must be parent passed to session (SaveOrUpdate(parent) 2) any child will be cascaded as described here http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-graphs. 3) In case of `save-udpate` delete will never be issued. 4) in case of 'all' delete will be issued only to currently holded and removed items. BUT in any case, there **must** be Parent and children collection available in the session to proceed these steps. this is weird: '..whether in the parent was retrieved by NHibernate or not'  Does this help?

Comment: Radim, I will check again, but in my integration test, cascade.SaveUpdate() was also issuing a delete.

Comment: Dan, I did test it locally, because I really wanted to be sure, that what I do believe in... is correct. And I have to say, that `save-update` cascade setting will NEVER fire DELETE on a child. If this is happening to you, please, check that you are on a latest version. I wish to help you, because NHibernate is awesome tool. But in this case... I did my best I could with info I have... Anyhow. Please, if you can, rethink your architecture. Cascading on detached objects could be tricky. And please, try to double check if the cascade is what you need. Maybe custome WRITE handling would be better

Comment: I have a test that confirms this (see edit above).  We are using NHibernate 3.3.1  I love NHibernate.  I usually assume I am not doing something right when it doesn't work.  we are implementing NHibernate in existing legacy apps and have to make NHibernate play nice with other parts of the application.  I want NHibernate to handle as much of the DB messiness as possible as long as the relationships are clear.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I did my best to explain what you've experienced. Maybe try to use Profiler to check that I am right. Cascade and NHibernate are working as expected/designed. Once you will trust me (if ever;), please, try to rethink your approach based on all info I gave you. Good luck

Comment: this isn't about trust. I was just trying to figure out what was going on.  I checked the SQL generated and you are correct.  It is not issuing a delete.  It was just disassociating the children through an update.  I was hoping there was a way to update changes, and still protect children.  Thank you for all your help.  I would love to re-engineer this application, but I am working with a lot of legacy code and using NHibernate for all new dev.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct since custom save seems to be the only way to achieve what I hoped could be done through mapping.

Comment: I am really sorry, that I cannot help more here. I understand what you write. I do. Anyhow, please, do not give up with NHibernate. It is amazing tool